# Can anyone help me to fix the 8 Errors i get on w3cvalidation related to Facebook Like & Google+ on my website?

Tags: w3c-validation

This is my site : http://abconlinesolutions.com/akashbc/main.html

See the errors found on w3cvalidation : 
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fabconlinesolutions.com%2Fakashbc%2Fmain.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3

Any one please help me to fix those 8 errors..

Here are the headline of the errors :

**1. Line 628, Column 13: there is no attribute "src"

1. Line 628, Column 292: there is no attribute "scrolling"
       …&appId=226098524153861" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
       style="border:none;…
2. Line 628, Column 309: there is no attribute "frameborder"
       …524153861" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;
       overflow:hidden;…
3. Line 628, Column 319: there is no attribute "style" … scrolling="no"
   frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200…
4. Line 628, Column 409: there is no attribute "allowTransparency" …en;
   width:200px; height:62px;padding: 10px;"
   allowTransparency="true">
5. Line 628, Column 415: element "iframe" undefined …en; width:200px;
   height:62px;padding: 10px;" allowTransparency="true">
6. Line 635, Column 23: there is no attribute "annotation"
7. Line 635, Column 31: element "g:plusone" undefined **

Anyone please help me...

Thank you all :)

Comment: well one simple solution, _don't go for `XHTML`, be with simple `HTML 5`_

Answer (score 0):

Put this DTD at the first line of your HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```